# Why does this script work on my computer, but not on another computer?

Tags: excel, macos, applescript, automator

I have a really simple script for cleaning up Microsoft Excel spreadsheets. It works perfectly on my computer, but when I tried to send it to a colleague, it did not work for him. Here is the code:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
  tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
    delete column 22
    delete column 21
    delete column 20
    -- this continues until column 1
    delete column 1
end tell
tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
    set value of cell "E27" to "=D27-2500"
    set value of cell "E28" to "=D28-2500"
    -- this continues a number of times as well
    set value of cell "E58" to "=D58-2500"
    set value of cell "F3" to "MEAN"
    set value of cell "G3" to "MEDIAN"
    set value of cell "H3" to "ST DEV"
  end tell
 end tell
```

When my colleague attempted to run this script, he received the following error:

```
error "Microsoft Excel got an error: Can’t set «class pval» of cell \"E27\" of «class cXLW» \"Sheet1\" to \"=D27-2500\"." number -10006 from «class pval» of cell "E27" of «class cXLW» "Sheet1"
```

In addition, his AppleScript editor changed the code, such that

```
delete column 22
```

turns into

```
«event XCELdelo» column 22
```

and

```
set value of cell "E27" to "=D27-2500"
```

turns into

```
set «class pval» of cell "E27" to "=D27-2500"
```

How do I get this script to work on my coworker's computer?

Comment: You should give more details about the computers and excel versions.

Answer (score 0):

it is likely that you are running different versions of excel. What I recommend is that your colleague upgrade or you upgrade. If you need to upgrade the script may need to be modified.

however the script may still work with different versions. What you can do to see if this will work is.

open the script in script editor on your colleague's machine and recompile it then run it and see if any errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile text into AppleScript, the AppleScript Editor always changes it, at least slightly, based on the target application’s AppleScript Dictionary and the Mac OS you are running. On your computer, your AppleScript is targeting your version of Excel on your version of OS X. On your colleague’s computer, your AppleScript is targeting his or her version of Excel on his or her version of OS X. If the versions of Excel are different, an AppleScript code block targeting the application “Excel” will compile differently on each system. On your colleague’s system, some of the commands and properties that you used simply don’t exist, and so you see the raw Apple Event, such as “«event XCELdelo»” instead of “delete.” If your OS X versions are different, that can also be a problem, because you are literally running different versions of AppleScript.

If your colleague wants to run your Excel AppleScript, he or she will have to do one of the following:

1. use the same version of Excel as you use, and possibly the same version of OS X
2. rewrite your AppleScript based on the AppleScript Dictionary for the version of Excel that he or she uses, which can be dramatically different than the AppleScript dictionary for the version of Excel that you use — he or she may have to replace the missing “delete” command with an “erase” command, for example, or there may not be a command in his or her version of Excel that corresponds to “delete.”

In short, where you use something like:

```
tell application "Excel"
```

… you should think of it as really saying:

```
tell application "Excel 10 on Mac OS X 10.9"
```

… or whatever version of Excel and OS X you are using. There is no guarantee that your AppleScript will run on a different version of Excel and/or OS X.